# How to change appbars background color dynamically?

Tags: android, kotlin

So In my application there are 3 appbars. One of them is the main appbar, in some fragments under the main appbar there is an another appbar for search and the last one is an appbar for some text.

I would like to change the background color by the fragment, so when the user enter to a new fragment, I would like to change the color by of appbar.

I found the solution, how to change the color, but I have to change for each appbar individually, it is good but not the best.

I would like to achive that, for example in Main Activity I set up the background color and after that, this set up all of the appbar color automatically.

Is there any way to achive this?

```
At present I do it by this code in Main Activity:

if(...){
   viewModel.toolbarDrawable.value = ColorDrawable(Color.RED)
   supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.RED))
   binding.appBarMain.mainAppbar.background = ColorDrawable(Color.RED)  
}else {
   viewModel.toolbarDrawable.value = ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE)
   supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE))
   binding.appBarMain.mainAppbar.background = ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE)  
}

And in search fragment

        mainActivityViewModel.toolbarDrawable.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,{
            baseBinding.toolbar.searchToolbarAppbar.background = it
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming your application is Single Activity application, perhaps you can implement the Toolbar manually instead by adding `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` in `MainActivity`, and use theme of `NoActionBar` for your application

(themes.xml)

```
<style name="Theme.AppName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

Add toolbar in your `activity_main.xml`

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />
```

And in your `MainActivity`, set color each time navigating to other fragment

```
val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
val toolbarBackgroundColor = when(destination.label) {
    "FirstFragment" -> R.color.design_default_color_primary
    "SecondFragment" -> R.color.design_default_color_secondary
    else -> R.color.black
}
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(toolbarBackgroundColor))
```

Comment: Thanks, it is good, but this code is only affects the activity main appbar toolbar, so in the search fragment there is an another appbar which is not affected by the toolbar color change.

Comment: Yeah, the current solution applicable for single toolbar in single activity. I was thinking about designing customized Toolbar, which contains Title and Search bar, therefore can set title and search bar visibility based on the fragment attached